# Custom ActionBar back click does not works

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, back

I'm created an android app in Eclipse. I tried to create custom action bar and using **setDisplayShowHomeEnabled** from **getActionbar** method to retrieve the icon actually. But then I setIcon to some kind of back_arrow image to look more like back arrow. I'm using **onOptionsItemSelected** to click my back button in customize action bar, but doesn't work for me. Switch case with **android.R.id.home**.

**Customize action bar in FragmentActivity:**

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

**BackButton action bar in Fragment:**

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActivity().getActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.left_back));

switch(item.getItemId()){
  case android.R.id.home:
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please change your code like this

```
   switch(item.getItemId()){
      case android.R.id.home:
           finish();
           return true;
    }
```

Comment: If you aren't trying to go back to the last activity, either call your onBackPressed function to go back or pop the fragment backstack, whichever you are looking for.